# Pattern matching on if block

Tags: bash, test, patterns

I'm trying to match a pattern stored in a variable through an if block. As per my understanding, this should be a match and get "Match" echo statement. However, it doesn't seems to be matching.

```
patern=EOD*psv
file=EOD_test_20160404.psv

if [[ $file == *"$patern" ]]
then
    echo "Match";
else
    echo "No Match";
fi
```

**Output:**

> No Match

Why doesn't the `file` variable value match the specified pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

So when you include double-quotes in the pattern, bash expects to see them in the filename. Drop the double-quotes and/or the leading `*` for success.

```
if [[ $file == $patern ]]
then
    echo "Match";
else
    echo "No Match";
fi
```